# Hide video and display only poster on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code to show a header video on my homepage

```
<video id="heroVideo" autoplay muted playsinline poster="/img/bc_hero-poster2.jpg">
  <source src="img/bc_hero2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="img/bc_hero2.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

For some reason it doesn't autoplay inline on iOS devices, is there any chance to hide the video and show only the poster image on mobiles and tablets?

Thank you

Comment: You're going to degrade the experience for all mobile devices just because it doesn't work on iOS? Also, I don't see why the code above will not work on iOS, since you have `muted` and `playsinline` enabled, it should autoplay by itself: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Comment: @Terry ye I know it should, but it doesn't and I've tried everything, even posting a separate thread here about it and no solution.

Comment: Try reproducing your issue in a minimal, concrete and verifiable example. What if you just use that very markup on the page and load it on iOS Safari? Does it auto play?

Comment: @Terry That actually helped! One plugin was causing trouble. Just one thing. There's a thin light grey border around the video on ios after it plays. Do you know if its possible to remove that somehow, please?